# Using docplex with mpmath

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming

In Python 3.10, is it possible to use docplex along with mpmath (https://mpmath.org/), e.g., to compute expressions in constraints and objectives with arbitrary precision?

Comment: Do you want to display the solution precision with an arbitrary number in docplex? If so, why not try to use docplex own method? do you have any force to use `mpmath`?

Comment: No. Constraints and objectives are evaluated inside the solver. Of course, the question is: why would you want that? I assume you have a poorly scaled model. I would work on that problem. But notice that solvers will scale your problem.